# how does numpy's polyvander3d work?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, polynomial-math

here is the reference
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander3d.html

I'm not sure how to decode the return value of this function

so what i want to have is basically an xyz polynomial of 2 degrees:

[image: polynomial]
I cant seem to figure out how to decode this example:

(x,y,z) = (3,3,3) and the degrees are [2,2,2]

```
>>>polyvander3d(3, 3, 3, [2, 2, 2] )
    array([[  1.,    3.,    9.,    3.,    9.,   27.,    9.,   27.,   81.,
              3.,    9.,   27.,    9.,   27.,   81.,   27.,   81.,  243.,
              9.,   27.,   81.,   27.,   81.,  243.,   81.,  243.,  729.]])
```

in addition, the documentation says:

> The leading indices of V index the points (x, y, z) and the last index encodes the powers of x, y, and z.

I have no idea what they mean by this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think that confusing piece of documentation is best described lower down the page as _"The shape of the returned matrix is `x.shape + (order,)`, where ..."_

Comment: Your biggest confusion point I think is that a Vandermonde matrix is somewhat useless with one scalar input.  Usually `x,y,z` are at least 1-D arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polyvander3d(x, y, z, [x_deg, y_deg, z_deg])` returns a matrix where each column has shape of `((x_deg+1)*(y_deg+1)*(z_deg+1), )` and contains all 3D polynomial coefficients in the order `c000, c001, c002, ..., c010, c011...`

So, using your example, the first column of the returned matrix contains (`V[0]`) contains all the 3d polynomial coefficients:

```
>>>V = polyvander3d(3, 3, 3, [2, 2, 2])
>>>V
array([[  1.,    3.,    9.,    3.,    9.,   27.,    9.,   27.,   81.,
          3.,    9.,   27.,    9.,   27.,   81.,   27.,   81.,  243.,
          9.,   27.,   81.,   27.,   81.,  243.,   81.,  243.,  729.]])
```

as in:

```
V[0][0] = (3^0 + 3^0 + 3^0) = 1
V[0][1] = (3^0 + 3^0 + 3^1) = 3
V[0][2] = (3^0 + 3^0 + 3^2) = 9
V[0][3] = (3^0 + 3^1 + 3^0) = 3
V[0][4] = (3^0 + 3^1 + 3^1) = 9
```

and so on until

```
V[0][(x_deg+1)*(y_deg+1)*(z_deg+1) - 1] = V[0][26] = (3^2 + 3^2 + 3^2) = 729
```

[Here's the most current link to the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander3d.html) (the one in the question leads to numpy v1.10).